# Execution Plan is different in `exec sp_executesql` and plain `SELECT`

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, sql-execution-plan

I created long Linq-to-SQL expression. As you may know internally Linq-to-SQL uses `exec sp_executesql` for query execution. When I run it in my app - it crashes with 30 sec timeout exception.

Then I copied resulting SQL from SQL Server Profiler to SQL Server Management Studio, replaced `exec sp_executesql` with plain `SELECT` and tried to debug it - it executes in 4 sec. As I see its execution plan much shorter and better.

Then I reverted back to `exec sp_executesql` and I see the execution plan is bad again. Any ideas? Is there any workaround?

**UPDATE:** Sirs, I found the reason. `exec sp_executesql` **caches** wrong plan and then uses it forever. When I add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query - it starts to work fast again. But I can't find how to add it to Linq-to-SQL queries?

Comment: have you try `UPDATE STATISTICS ?` on your SQL server?

Comment: yes, it consumes 5 secs but does not help ..

Answer (score 0):

Forced to create a dirty hack, but it works at least...

```
public static class XQueryableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        bool recompile)
    {
        if (!recompile)
            return source.AsEnumerable<T>();
        FieldInfo field =
            source.GetType().GetField(
                "context",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (field == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("'field' is null");
        DataContext dataContext = field.GetValue(source) as DataContext;
        if (dataContext == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("'dataContext' is null");
        if (dataContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            dataContext.Connection.Open();
        using (DbCommand command = dataContext.GetCommand(source)) {
            command.CommandText += " OPTION (RECOMPILE)";
            using (DbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) {
                return dataContext.Translate<T>(dataReader).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```